# TP-WR841N password not working after firmware upgrade and config restore

Tags: wireless-router, password-recovery

I have been having issues with WiFi drop-outs recently, and decided to upgrade my firmware. Router is a TL-WR841N.

Upgrade completed, but all settings were reverted to defaults, so I restored the backup I took moments before upgrade (phew!). I am back online now, but the password no loner works. I've tried all defaults and the password saved in browser that used to work, but I cannot get in.

The config was setup by ISP and I cannot reset it as I don't know what to set the values to.

I'm guessing the config from backup of old firmware isn't fully compatible with 
the new firmware and the password although set from the backup, isn't what it should be!

I've also used RouterPassView to read the backup file and confirm the password is what I was using.

Comment: It would appear that only your ISP can fix this ...

Comment: Some routers come with a hard default password that is printed on a sticker at their bottom; check there.